# What happen when client disconnected?

Tags: php, networking

When a browser send a http request to a web server. And that request will run a PHP script which will call function A, B and C.

If the browser's connection lost while the PHP executing function A, will it keep running the script and call function B and C?

Comment: I think yes. Try with some txt log or some db insert maybe

Comment: PHP will continue executing until it tries to perform output, which is when it'll discover that the connection has been closed, and that'll trigger it to shut down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PHP this is simply controlled within the ini file:

```
; If enabled, the request will be allowed to complete even if the user aborts
; the request. Consider enabling it if executing long requests, which may end up
; being interrupted by the user or a browser timing out. PHP's default behavior
; is to disable this feature.
; http://php.net/ignore-user-abort
;ignore_user_abort = On
```

By default, in PHP 5.6.3, the behavior is to kill the script if you close your **browser**. Closing your tab, at least in Chrome, does not kill the script. You must close the browser.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the traditional HTTP model is not an interactive model.
The only way to make *definitely* sure that your script doesn't run if the user has closed the page is:
1. Include these lines in the beginning of your script:
`<?php
 ob_implicit_flush();
 ob_end_flush();
 ...`
2. For code you don't want running after a user has quit:

```
<?php
 if(!connection_aborted()){
  //your code here
 }
```

Hope this helps ...